# Why is main method used in JavaFX Application when start() already exist

Tags: java

The starting point for a JavaFX application is start method. But in the sample JavaFX applications, there is a main method included as well. What is the use of main method in this particular case and why was there a need to define start() as starting point for JavaFX. Couldn't we simply use the main method to define a starting point like Swings?

A sample HelloWorld application:

```
public class HelloWorld extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Button btn = new Button("Hello World");
        btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Hello World!");
            }
        });

        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        root.getChildren().add(btn);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. The accepted answer from @SuvarnaPattayil perfectly addresses the first part of OP's question. I'm also interested in the second part of the question -- *why was there a need to define start() as starting point for JavaFX. Couldn't we simply use the main method to define a starting point like Swings?*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.htm) ,

> The main() method is not required for JavaFX applications when the JAR
>   file for the application is created with the JavaFX Packager tool,
>   which embeds the JavaFX Launcher in the JAR file. However, it is
>   *useful to include* the main() method so you can run JAR files that were
>   created without the JavaFX Launcher, such as when using an IDE in
>   which the JavaFX tools are not fully integrated. Also, Swing
>   applications that embed JavaFX code require the main() method.