# JavaFX program doesn't run in nogui command line mode

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx-2

I wrote JavaFX application that can be execute in two modes. With GUI and without.

If command line command has two parameters then cli selected, else gui:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    if (args != null && args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("cli")) {
        String pathToProperties = args[1];
        Cli cli = new Cli(pathToProperties);
        cli.loadPropertiesAndGenerateApk();
    } else {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

In Intellij IDEA when I click `Run` button everything works fine.

But when I build artifacts (.jar file) and try to run in cli mode -- GUI opens:

```
java -jar JavaFXApp.jar cli /path/toconfig.properties
```

Does anybody know why?

Update: I added `System.out.println(args[0])` as @fdsa asked. And see that program launch in terminal no message:
https://yadi.sk/i/uwGT4EpVkDCea

Comment: Have you tried printing out `args[0]` to see what it contains?

Comment: Yes. I have tried to `System.out.println("some text");` but no success. Like that code never reach `if` statement. But code inside `main()`. I will add to question addition info

Comment: Can you `System.out.println(args[0])` before the if statement?

Comment: @fdsa done. Still no message

Comment: If that is the very first line, I would guess that you're running an old version of the program from the command line

Comment: @fdsa I thought that and added few lines to view file and it changed. Maybe something wrong with Intellij IDEA build? I will check

Comment: @fdsa I ve found that script invoke only `public void start(Stage primaryStage)` but not main() method. May be you know why?

Comment: Seems I've found why: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160947/why-is-main-method-used-in-javafx-application-when-start-already-exist